# Yii update with join

Tags: yii

I have a code

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->update(
            'queue q',
            array('i.status_id' => $status_id)
        )
        ->join('item i', 'q.item_id = i.item_id')
        ->where('IN', 'queue_id', $ids);
```

after I call $command->buildQuery() I get an error:

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined. The SQL statement executed was: UPDATE `queue q` SET `i`.`status_id`=:i.status_id

The impression is that it does not see the join and where commands. 
What the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is valid with the newest Yii version. This MySQL-specific functionality has been added as of 1.1.14: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/commit/ed49b77ca059c0895be17df5813ee1e83d4c916d.

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the parameters:

```
$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
    ->update(
        'queue q',
        array('i.status_id' => ':status_id'),
        array('in', 'queue_id', $ids),
        array(':status_id' => $status_id),
    )
    ->join('item i', 'q.item_id = i.item_id');
```

Comment: I've tried. In this case, it says that number of parameters and their entries must be the same. Another words parameters for where only expected.
Moreover, look closely, this parameters calls ":i.status_id" automatically

Comment: Try then to set the where clause before bind the parameters. I have updated the answer.

Comment: This isn't supported, binding an array of values only works with CDbCriteria not CDbCommand.

Answer (score 0):

The where clause should be in the update() function like this

```
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->update(
            'queue q',
            array('i.status_id' => $status_id),array('in', 'queue_id', $ids)
        );
```

And regarding the JOIN part there is a open bug at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/124 (Im not sure. Correct me if Im wrong). Please let me know if there is a workaround.

Comment: There is no difference. Since where parameter in update method is optional. But I'l tried - same effect.

Comment: but you given the parametes of where as `where('IN', 'queue_id', $ids)` ,instead it should be `where(array('in', 'queue_id', $ids))`

Answer (score 0):

Having come across this problem a few times in my projects I have come-up with the following Yii work-around using CDbCriteria which is a little hacky, but gives the security of param count matching.

When applied to your example my code would be (guessing a little bit of your structure):

```
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition('i.queue_id',$ids);

$sql = '
  UPDATE queue q
    JOIN item i 
      ON q.item_id = i.item_id
     SET i.status_id = :status
   WHERE '.$criteria->condition;

$command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
$command->bindValue('status',$status);
$command->bindValues($criteria->params);
$rows = $command->execute();
```